# Inconsistent response (JSON array lengths different) from Google Places API

Tags: json, httpresponse, google-places-api

When I make GET HTTP call to Google Places API. (Example Call: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=") ....

Under "results", inconsistent number of elements are returned. What is the base list of fields that will always be returned?

In the screenshot below, you can see how the array length count under "results" is different, counts are 11, 10, 10, and 8.

[image]

Screenshot below shows how one the JSON Arrays in the response has more elements than the other and the extra fields are circled in red.

[image: Different number of JSON elements in array]

I am confused here because I am trying to write code to parse the JSON and trying to understand which are the fields to expect? Missing fields in some arrays in the response is breaking my code.

Am I interpreting the API documentation incorrectly or Is this a bug that I should be filing with Google directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using logic that does not require any fields at all.  Because the server is out of your control, it could return anything at any time (due to API changes, bugs, technical faults, etc.)

For example, in [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets) I loop through whatever objects are returned and if the name matches something that I expect, then I process it.  Otherwise the fields in my objects simply remain empty.  You can see the top-level processing Java code in the [PlacesResponse](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/sprockets/google/Places.java#L1308) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, but documented behaviour.  The [Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses) says:

> Each result within the results array **may** contain the following fields:

In other words, Google returns ratings, opening hours etc for places *if* it has them, but it will leave them out if it does not or the field is not relevant to the place (eg. you wouldn't have opening hours for an apartment complex or rate a train station).  As @pushbit says, you have to parse accordingly and check whether each field was returned.